# Expected value of product of dependent Poisson random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation, poisson-distribution

I would like to compute

$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[Y\sum_{j=1}^{Y}X_j\bigg]$$

where $Y\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda>0$ and the $\big\{X_j\big\}$ are iid with $X_j\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ for some $p\in(0,1)$. The variable $Y$ and the $X_j$ are assumed to be independent.

I'm not sure how to go about this, because it's the product of two *dependent* Poisson random variables. Tips appreciated.

Comment: Condition on $Y$.

Comment: Does that mean to compute $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[Y\sum_{j=1}^YX_j\ |\ Y=k]\cdot\mathbb{P}[y=k]$?

Comment: More simply, compute $E(Y\sum\limits_{j=1}^YX_j\mid Y=n)$ for every $n$ and see what happens.

Comment: It seems like that equals $pn^2$, but then I get stuck on the resulting infinite sum. Am I moving in the right direction?

Comment: So, you know that the random variable $Z$ which interests you is such that $E(Z\mid Y)=pY^2$ and you are looking for $E(Z)$. Sure you cannot conclude?

Comment: Ooooh I see. That works out nicely. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$According to the law of total expectation,
\begin{align}
& \e\left( Y \sum_{j=1}^Y X_j \right) = \e\left( \e\left( Y \sum_{j=1}^Y X_j \,\Big\vert\, Y \right) \right) = \e\left( Y \e\left( \sum_{j=1}^Y X_j \right) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \e\left( Y (Yp) \right) = p\e\left( Y^2\right) = p \left( \lambda+\lambda^2 \right)
\end{align}